# How to validate a account number using javascript?

Tags: javascript

`var expression=/[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{4}\s[0-9]{2}\s[0-9]{10}/;`

This is the expression iam using for validating a account number. it is working very well. but i need to validate it by - instead of space. how can i do it?

```
eg: XXXX-XXXX-XX-XXXXXXXXXX (4+4+2+10)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace all those `'\s'` markers with `'-'`. Outside of the character class range `'[]'`, `'-'` is treated as a normal character (inside the range, you would have to escape it thus: `'\-'`)

Answer (score 2):

Replace `\s` with `-` you get:

```
var expression=/[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{10}/;
expression.test('4444-4444-22-01234567890') /*return true*/
```

Replace `\s` with `""` you get:

```
var expression=/[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{2}[0-9]{10}/;
expression.test('444444442201234567890') /*return true*/
```

Comment: Arun start your regx with ^ and end it with $ sign to restrict the length otherwise you can add as many number as you want in the end.

`var expression=/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{10}$/;`

Comment: Haroon Yousuf Thanks for that.